# Incoherent frame prediction for Moving MNIST using ConvLSTM in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm relatively new to Convolutional LSTM networks, but I am currently working on a problem that involves the prediction of a sequence of frames in the future, which is why I have decided to look into ConvLSTM networks.

To get a feel for how the model works and how I could extend the model, I have tried some initial tests on the Moving MNIST dataset available here:
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~nitish/unsupervised_video/mnist_test_seq.npy

However, after training and running inference - I would have thought the predictions would be more coherent, especially when comparing to other people who have used similar approaches for the Moving MNIST dataset. It seems like the original trajectory of the digits are "saved" in the output.

**Is this a common limitation or is my network architecture designed incorrectly for the task at hand?**

#### Setup

I have read and applied the code given in the following article:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04214

and they also have a Github page, where I have largely used their keras example for the ConvLSTM cell:
https://github.com/wqxu/ConvLSTM

I have reduced the sample size to 100 for you to replicate the results - but I have trained the model with a K40 GPU for 100 epochs (takes about an hour) just to see if the issue is related to model simply not converging.

My code is as follows (assuming you have downloaded the Moving MNIST dataset from the above link and put it into the 'path' variable):

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = "./"
data = np.load(path + 'mnist_test_seq.npy')

# Define image dimensions and frames to be used for LSTM memory
sequence_length = 15 
image_height = data.shape[2]
image_width = data.shape[3]

# swap frames and observations so [obs, frames, height, width, channels]
data = data.swapaxes(0, 1)

# only select first 100 observations to reduce memory- and compute requirements
sub = data[:100, :, :, :]
# add channel dimension (grayscale)
sub = np.expand_dims(sub, 4)

# normalize to 0, 1
#sub = sub / 255
sub[sub < 128] = 0
sub[sub>= 128] = 1


# Define network

seq = Sequential()
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,1),
                   input_shape=(None, image_height, image_width, 1), #Will need to change channels to 3 for real images
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True,
                   activation='relu'))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2,2),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True,
                   activation='relu'))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,1),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True,
                   activation='relu'))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())
seq.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(2,2),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True,
                   activation='relu'))
seq.add(BatchNormalization())
seq.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1,1,1),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
seq.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')


# Add helper function for shifting input and output, so previous frame (X_t-1) is used as input to predict next frame (y_t)

def shift_data(data, n_frames=15):
    X = data[:, 0:n_frames, :, :, :]
    y = data[:, 1:(n_frames+1), :, :, :]
    return X, y


# Run script

# prepare X, y
X, y = shift_data(sub, sequence_length)

# fit the model
seq.fit(X, y, batch_size=16, epochs=100, validation_split=0.05)

# select a random observation
test_set = np.expand_dims(X[5, :, :, :, :], 0)


# compare to ground truth and visualize
for i in range(0, 13):
    # create plot
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

    # truth
    ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
    ax.text(1, -3, ('ground truth at time :' + str(i)), fontsize=20, color='b')
    toplot_true = test_set[0, i, ::, ::, 0]
    plt.imshow(toplot_true)
    # predictions
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax.text(1, -3, ('predicted frame at time :' + str(i)), fontsize=20, color='b')
    toplot_pred = prediction[0, i+1, ::, ::, 0]

    plt.imshow(toplot_pred)
    plt.savefig(path + '/%i_image.png' % (i + 1))
```

The results I get are as follows:

First image looks quite good
[Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fagdO.png)

However, [Frame 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNRyW.png) and [Frame 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVjjD.png) frame clearly shows you the entire trajectory of the previous steps.

And if you visualize all images at once it also gets clear the trajectory of the digits never gets "removed" from the image.

I am uncertain if this is just some known limitation of the model or if it is just the model not converging. My concern is, that these results are not too satisfactory given the relative simplicity of the dataset, and that more complex tasks would simply be infeasible for the model.
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!